# What time/day does voting for the first EOS election start?

Tags: voting

When the EOS blockchain launches I read that the initial producers will be "self-appointed" and then the election process starts.

When does voting start and how long does it go on before the first elected block producers are known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no absolute answer for your question but here is some general advice (as taken from the community, not specifically my own)

After 5 or more Block Producer candidates declare publicly that the mainnet is ready for voting (*and you should trust those BP candidates are authentic, honest, and have worked closely with the launch team, and support only one mainnet*) ... then voting can start.

Details on how to vote will be supplied by the BP candidates. As always [please be careful and do not get scammed](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/the-eos-mainnet-launch-survival-guide-how-to-avoid-scams).

Once at least 15% of all votes are cast then those elected BPs run the mainnet.

How long it takes depends on how quickly tokenholders vote.

Remember voting is a fluid process: the top 21 BP can change.

**For anyone who is not completely sure of what to do:**

The safest course of action is to do nothing. You lose nothing by waiting a little longer and checking that all BPs are happy with the mainnet before participating. [This advice was discussed on the EOS Launch Party](https://youtu.be/FIGRRfr6LjA?t=2795).

Please read more here:

https://medium.com/@bensig/letter-to-eos-block-producer-candidates-184ef59a0748

https://steemit.com/eos/@eosdac/eos-mainnet-launch-the-order-of-events